# Kotlin ProcessBuilder Incorrectly Splitting Command, Leading to Multiple Arguments

Tags: linux, kotlin

I'm encountering an issue executing a command using Kotlin's ProcessBuilder. The command is being split into multiple arguments, resulting in an error: `at most 1 query string can be specified as an argument, got 10`.

**Relevant Code:**

```
override fun fetchRecords(startTime: String, stopTime: String, bucket: String): List<String> {
val result = runCommand(
    "influx query 'from(bucket: \"$bucket\") |> range(start: $startTime) |> pivot(rowKey: [\"_time\"], columnKey:[\"_field\"], valueColumn:\"_value\")'"
)
// ...
}

private fun runCommand(command: String, workingDir: File = File(".")): String {
    val parts = command.split("\\s".toRegex())
    val proc = ProcessBuilder(*parts.toTypedArray())
       // ...
}
```

**Error Message:**

`Command error: Error: at most 1 query string can be specified as an argument, got 10`

**Attempted Fixes:**

- I've tried using a multi-line string literal without explicit newline characters, but the error persists.

**Questions:**

- What's causing the incorrect argument splitting?
- How can I ensure the command is passed as a single argument?
  -Are there alternative approaches to executing commands in Kotlin that might avoid this issue?
- Should I consider using a different library for command execution?

**Additional Context:**

- I'm using Kotlin version `1.9.20`
- The command being executed is `influx query 'from(bucket: "1CATUSDTTimeSeries1Hour") |> range(start: 0) |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey:["_field"], valueColumn:"_value")'` which works fine with terminal.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why did you do `command.split("\\s".toRegex())`? `split` doesn't know about what quotes mean in a command. How about changing `runCommand` to take an `Array<String>`, or optionally `varargs`?

Comment: @Sweeper
when i pass `command`directly i get this error.
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "command ..."  (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay, never mind then, How about taking an `Array<String>` instead?

Comment: Or just pass the whole thing to `sh -c` (or whatever terminal you like) and have the shell split the arguments for you.

Comment: @Sweeper since your answer worked.
why you don't answer this question so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing the command line arguments yourself (which is not trivial), take an `Array<String>` instead, and let the caller split the arguments.

```
private fun runCommand(command: Array<String>, workingDir: File = File(".")): String {
    val proc = ProcessBuilder(*command)
    ...
}
```

```
val result = runCommand(
    arrayOf("influx", "query", 
    "from(bucket: \"$bucket\") |> range(start: $startTime) |> pivot(rowKey: [\"_time\"], columnKey:[\"_field\"], valueColumn:\"_value\")"
    )
)
```

Alternatively, send the whole command to `sh` (or whatever shell is on the system), and let it parse the arguments. This of course, is platform dependent.

```
private fun runCommand(command: String, workingDir: File = File(".")): String {
    val proc = ProcessBuilder(arrayOf("sh", "-c", command))
    ...
}
```